# Use of jquery.shapeshift to build a kanban board: how save info on db when event triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, kanban, shapeshift

I would like to create a kanban-like section on my website, I found [this jquery.shapeshift](https://github.com/McPants/jquery.shapeshift) system that's meet my needs, but I need some help to trigger events when user move items from one container to another as I'm not very good at coding in javascript.

I don't really need to save items position as I read items from a sql db. What I miss is a way to save changes to the db when user move one item say from "To do" list to "Completed". In that case I want to update the db record.

In the vb code I'm able to catch if an item is added to a container but I have no clue on how to catch item index or some info that helps me to update the db. This is the code behind in the page_load event:

```
Me.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Me, String.Empty)

        If IsPostBack Then 'Necessario per callServersideFunction()
            Dim eventTarget As String
            Dim eventArgument As String

            If Me.Request("__EVENTTARGET") Is Nothing Then
                eventTarget = String.Empty
            Else
                eventTarget = Me.Request("__EVENTTARGET")
            End If
            If Me.Request("__EVENTARGUMENT") Is Nothing Then
                eventArgument = String.Empty
            Else
                eventArgument = Me.Request("__EVENTARGUMENT")
            End If
            If eventTarget = "CustomPostBack" Then
                Dim valuePassed As String = eventArgument

            End If


        End If
```

My aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="kanban.aspx.vb" Inherits="Efesto.kanban2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="shapeshift/jquery.shapeshift.js"></script>
    <script src="shapeshift/vendor/jquery.touch-punch.min.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            border-left: 2px dashed #000;
            border-right: 2px dashed #000;
            border-bottom: 2px dashed #000;
            position: relative;
        }

            .container > div {
                background-color: antiquewhite;
                border: 1px solid black;
                height: 100px;
                position: absolute;
                width: 80px;
                box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(85,85,85,0.5);
            }

                .container > div[data-ss-colspan='2'] {
                    width: 170px;
                }

            .container .ss-placeholder-child {
                background: transparent;
                border: 1px dashed white;
            }

        .titolo {
            font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            border-left: 2px dashed #000;
            border-right: 2px dashed #000;
            border-top: 2px dashed #000;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .dafare {
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }

        .dafareoggi {
            background-color: #e93946;
        }

        .incorso {
            background-color: #eceda5;
        }

        .completate {
            background-color: #6ac276;
        }
    </style>

    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
        $(window).load(function () {
            $(".container").shapeshift({
                minColumns: 3
            }).on('ss-drop-complete', function () {
                // get the new arrangement and serialise it to localStorage as a string
                var value1 = $(this) + " " + $(selected);
                __doPostBack('CustomPostBack', value1);
            });
        });//]]> 

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div class="titolo dafare">DA FARE</div>
            <div class="container dafare ">
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptDaFare" DataSourceID="SqlAttivitaDaFare">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div><%# Eval("Titolo") %></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>

            </div>
            &nbsp;
        <div class="titolo dafareoggi">DA FARE OGGI</div>
            <div class="container dafareoggi">

                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <%--data-ss-colspan='2'--%>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
            &nbsp;
        <div class="titolo incorso">IN CORSO</div>
            <div class="container incorso ">

                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
            &nbsp;
        <div class="titolo completate">COMPLETATE</div>
            <div class="container completate">

                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <script>
                // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
                if (window.parent && window.parent.parent) {
                    window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
                        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
                        slug: "LNysC"
                    }], "*")
                }
            </script>
        </div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlAttivitaDaFare" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbVulcanoConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Attivita] WHERE (([Completato] = @Completato) AND ([DataFine] IS NULL) AND ([IDUtente] = @IDUtente)) ORDER BY [DataInser], [DataInizio], [Titolo]">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="False" Name="Completato" Type="Boolean" />
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="IDUtente" SessionField="idUtente" Type="Int16" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any helps is really appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out after some try and error:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
        $(window).load(function () {
            $(".container").shapeshift({
                minColumns: 3,
                align: "left"

            }).on("ss-added", function (e, selected) {
                var idAttivita = $(selected).attr("id");
                var idTargetDiv = $(this).attr("id");
                __doPostBack('modificaAttivita', idAttivita + ";" + idTargetDiv);
                //alert(idAttivita + ";" + idTargetDiv); // Returns the index position.
            });

        });//]]> 
</script>
```

idAttivita return the attribute "ID" of the child (the draggable div)
idTargetDiv return the attribute "ID" of the container div in which the child is dropped.
It is possible to play around with different events (here I used only "ss-added") thanks to the [reference guide](https://github.com/McPants/jquery.shapeshift/wiki/2.0-api-documentation)
Necessary condition to work like this: all the div involved in the shapeshift need to have a valid ID attribute, like:

```
<div class="container" id="container1">
      <div id="child1"></div>
</div>
```

In this example then idAttivita="child1" and idTargetDiv="container1"